# Do I have to use async/await when i use Firestore listen function?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following listen function:

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(widget.userId).snapshots().listen((event) 
    async{
     if(!event.metadata.isFromCache){
     String myFirstValue = await event.get('name');
     

    // here i have many local operations that depends on `myFirstValue` Constantly as the 
      document changes

     }
    
     });
```

In the previous code , after many tests I noticed that I can use `await` and  also I cannot use it like the following:

```
String myFirstValue = event.get('name');
```

In all cases I can get correct results.

I am totally confused, should I use `await` or not ?
What is the better use?
Is there some cases leads me to have errors in my operations that depend on my `myFirstValue` if I didn't use await?

In other words: does the `event` that comes from `.listen((event)` will have all values and there is no need to use await in `myFirstValue` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event` in your code is a `DocumentSnapshot`. If we check the reference documentation [`DocumentSnapshot.get`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/get.html) does not return a `Future`, so there's no need to use `await` when calling it.

That is different for [`DocumentReference.get()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html), which **does** return a `Future`. Using `await` here would unwrap the `Future` and give you the underlying `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: thanks @Frank , so in direct answer there no need to use await (according to my code)?